# updating a cart.i want to send the previous quantity and the new quantity

Tags: javascript, php

i want to send the new quantity,the previous quantity and the product id in the URL using javascript function.
this is update.php page.qty is the previous quantity and qty1 is the new quantity which is to be added to this.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('custdb1.php');
$qty = $_GET['qty'];
$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : '';
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST["id"];

    $qty = $_REQUEST["qty"];
    $_SESSION['cart'][$id] = array('id' => $id, 'qty' => $qty);
    echo "Quantity:" . $qty . '<br>';
    echo "Id:" . $id . '<br>';
    $sql = "SELECT `pro_img` FROM `product` WHERE `pro_id`=" . $id;
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<img src='upload/" . $row['pro_img'] . "'/>";
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Quantity: <input type='text' name='qty1' id='qty1" . $row["pro_id"] . "' value=''>";
            echo "<button onclick='up(" . $qty . "," . $id . ")'>update cart</button>";
        }
        //echo '<h4 align="center">  click here to <a href="update1.php?id='.$id.'&qty1='.$qty1.'&qty='.$qty.'">update cart</a> </h4>';
        // echo "<button onclick='up(".$qty.",".$id.")'>update cart</button>" ;
    }
}

//echo '<h4 align="center">  click here to <a href="update1.php?id='.$id.'&qty='.$qty1.'&qty='.$qty.'">update cart</a> </h4>';
?>
<script>
    function up(qty, id)
    {
        var qty1 = document.getElementById('qty1' + id).value;
        window.location = "update1.php?id=" + id + "&qty=" + qty + "qty1=" + qty1;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: what is the issue you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to me but there is an error when you are trying to redirect it. You are missing `&` when binding `qty1`.

Your code should be

```
window.location ="update1.php?id="+id+"&qty="+qty+"&qty1="+qty1;
return false; // use return false always when redirecting your page.
```